# Using a Variable in Excel for COUNTIF

Tags: excel, variables, spreadsheet, formula, countif

First time question and I hope it's easier than I'm making this.

Can I use a variable inside a `COUNTIF` formula?

Currently my formula is:

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$415,R6)
```

I would like to have `$415` as my variable. I have tried something along the lines of:

```
D1=415=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$(D1),R6) ..
```

but obviously get a error.

The reason I need this is column C will constantly be incrementing as I add more rows.

Instead of going into each of my formulas and updated 415 to 416, 417 etc, I would like to just define a Cell that can be my variable, or total rows.

Currently Column C can have blank cells, so I can't have a macro that finds the next empty cell.. but I do however have Column A with a constant populated cell and stops at the last ticket. However Column A is unrelated to the `COUNTIF`.

**UPDATE 1**

I'd also like to mention that I'd be using this variable in many formulas in the spreadsheet. Not only `COUNTIF`'s. Also, the `COUNTIF` contains text.

***UPDATE 2***

Actually, I figured it out! I am using this formula instead:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C"&D1&":A"&D2),R6)
```

I'm putting `D1=2` and `D2=415` and will just update cell D2 with how many rows I have.

I guess I just needed to ask the question thoroughly to fully understand what I wanted!

Thank you in advance for all help, tips and suggestions.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! I am using this formula instead:

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C"&D1&":A"&D2),R6)

I'm putting D1=2 and D2=415 and will just update cell D2 with how many rows I have.

I guess I just needed to ask the question thoroughly to fully understand what I wanted!

Comment: But why not use the whole column? 415 is not _that_ much number of rows and using the whole column won't hinder performance by a lot. And by the way, shouldn't it be `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C"&D1&":C"&D2),R6)` instead?

Comment: I'd use the whole column. COUNTIF (along with the whole family of IF/IFS functions) only uses the "used range" even when the whole column is specified - INDIRECT is a volatile function so the performance "hit" is arguably going to be worse using that version than the whole column. Alternatively INDEX is better than INDIRECT, i.e.

Comment: You are right, =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C"&D1&":C"&D2),R6) is what it is. Sorry for my mistype.

Comment: As an aside, `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and is usually avoided.  It sounds like what you're looking for is a [dynamic named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would "=COUNTIF($C:$C,R6)" do the trick? This will apply COUNTIF to the whole of column C. It's an easy solution, but probably not the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer tables for storing data; as new data is added, the table automatically expands and the columns are already labeled (much like Named Ranges).  Then you can have =COUNTIF(Table1[Column1],"Criteria"), which will encompass any new rows added to the table automatically.  Especially helpful if you have multiple tables in the same column.